# Postgresql - How to select multiple tables by specific columns and append them

Tags: postgresql, select, append

I would like to select a number of tables and select the geometry (geom) and Name columns in each of the tables and append below each other. I have gotten as far as selecting the tables and their columns as shown below:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE (TABLE_NAME LIKE '%HESA' OR 
      TABLE_NAME LIKE '%HEWH') AND 
      (COLUMN_NAME = 'geom' AND
       COLUMN_NAME = 'Name');
```

How do you then take the tables:

```
id | geom  | Name  |  id | geom  | Name  |
____________________  ____________________
1  | geom1 | Name1 |  1  | geom4 | Name4 |
2  | geom2 | Name2 |  2  | geom5 | Name5 |
3  | geom3 | Name3 |  3  | geom6 | Name6 |
```

And append the second table below the first, like this:

```
id | geom  | Name  |
____________________
1  | geom1 | Name1 |
2  | geom2 | Name2 |
3  | geom3 | Name3 |
1  | geom4 | Name4 |
2  | geom5 | Name5 |
3  | geom6 | Name6 |
```

Do I use UNION ALL or something else?

Comment: please build env on rextester or db-fiddle or elsewhere and I will help you, otherwise simplify the case, provide the code and data sample for minimal reproducible env

Comment: i don't understand how you get your `id | geom  | Name  |  id | geom  | Name  |` table. That's output is not possible with the query in the question..(or iám complety misreading/misunderstanding your question)

Comment: From your question I would guess that `UNION ALL` is what you're looking for. In this case it actually looks like the tables are partitioned so that might be an option too. To help you it would be useful if you could create an SQLFiddle with some demo data: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @VaoTsun So I created a test env in fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3418/2 , Basically I want to select 3 tables with very different names, so I need to use LIKE (I want to select a lot more tables my actual case). I then want to select just two of the columns, geom and name from each table and append them under each other. So I would end up with a new table with just two columns, geom and name. I would like to store this output as a new table in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/75fgQMEWf9LvPj4xYMGWvA/0

based on your sample data:

```
do
'
declare
 r record;
begin
 for r in (
SELECT a.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns a
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns b on a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME and a.COLUMN_NAME = ''geom'' and b.COLUMN_NAME = ''name''
WHERE (a.TABLE_NAME LIKE ''oranges%'' OR a.TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%_db'') 
 ) loop
    execute format(''insert into rslt select geom, name from %I'',r.table_name);
 end loop;
end;
'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Union All will do the job just fine:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM table_one)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM table_two)
) AS tmp
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

I have added the external SELECT, to show you how you can order the whole result.

DB Fiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2arw2avKQX4GM8ZKFEL68u/1)

Comment: I have taken a look at your DB Fiddle and it does what I want, except in my case I have many tables (200+) each with titles that are broken down by region (01 - 09) and type (HEHB, CFFC, TMTS, RSRC etc.) So a table title would be 01HEHB or 09CFFC for instance. I want to combine all HEHB and CFFC tables and keep only two of the columns, in this case id, geom and name. In your example I would need to call UNION ALL over and over. Is there a way of streamlining this?

Comment: Your best option is to write a stored procedure in PL/pgSQL.